# Different content for different domains in 1 file

Tags: php

trying to have a index.php file for 3 different domains... so I need to display different content for the different domains. But want it to work also on "sub folders" for sub folders I mean site1.com/some_content

this is my code but it doesn't work as I want.

```
<?php
    $host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if($host == 'site1.com')  {
        echo "A LOT OF HTML JAVASCRIPT AND CSS";
    }
    if($host == 'site2.com')  {
        echo "Same here but different content";
    }
    if($host == 'site3.com')  {
        echo "Cats and flowers";
    }
?>
```

any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Leave only `$host = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`. You don't need the `REQUEST_URI`

Comment: Use `echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` and `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to do basic debugging. It would have been obvious why your code does not work.

Comment: remove $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Apache, you could define something like this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^development.example.com$" APPLICATION_ENV=development
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^staging.example.com$"     APPLICATION_ENV=staging
SetEnvIfNoCase Host "^example.com$"             APPLICATION_ENV=production
```

Then, in your index.php file (or whatever you include on every page load) add this:

```
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));
```

Afterwards, you can read the value of `APPLICATION_ENV` anywhere in your code to determine what environment you are on at the moment like this:

```
switch (APPLICATION_ENV) {
   case 'development':
       // do stuff
       break;

   case 'staging':
       // do stuff
       break;

   case 'production':
   default:
       // do stuff
       break;
}
```

You can point multiple hostnames to the same IP/host in your /etc/hosts (or C:/Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts) file like this (assuming it's on localhost):

```
127.0.0.1 development.example.com
127.0.0.1 staging.example.com
127.0.0.1 example.com
```

I know having a global constant is not idea, but it's better than relying on HTTP_HOST as that can easily be changed.

Comment: wow! thanks! yeah you right that's deff much better! thank you andris :)

Answer (score 0):

`$host = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];`
You dont need the rest.

I will have to notice that very likely you are doing something wrong.
At least create 3 different scripts instead or rather map each domain to a different directory with it's own scripts. It's a bad practice to have such a mess in the code.